# SQLite attendance date records table structure | delete where | primary key

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, database-design

I have a Xamarin.Forms app I'm building with a SQLite database. I want to keep records of students' attendance. I wanted to make an attendance table with just 2 columns:

```
public class Attendance
{
    public DateTime AttendanceDate { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I run into is with the delete method. The DeleteAsync method simply takes a primary key, something like this:

```
db.DeleteAsync<Attendance>(primaryKey)
```

But I found out that SQLite does not support concatenated primary keys. So when a user wants to delete an attendance record I don't have a primary key to pass in to delete the record. The only workaround I can think of would be to:

- add an auto-incremented number for the primary key
- use a select statement to find the record matching the date and studentID
- then after finding the primary key matching those parameters, run the delete operation with the primary key.

Is there a way to pass in a WHERE clause with the DeleteAsync method? Something like this:

```
db.DeleteAsync<Attendance>(
    where (date == dateVariable && studentID == idVariable) )
```

Or do I need to change the table structure to add an auto-incremented primary key?

Comment: you can just use `Query` to run a delete query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Jason, you can delete the this `Attendance` by `QueryAsync`

```
Database.QueryAsync<Attendance>("DELETE FROM Attendance WHERE AttendanceDate =? AND StudentID =? ",attendance.AttendanceDate ,attendance.StudentID);
```

Or if you can get the `Attendance` model. You can delete by `Attendance` model.

```
var attendance=new Attendance() { AttendanceDate= DateTime.Now,StudentID=1 };
Database.DeleteAsync<Attendance>(attendance);
```

Comment: Yes @Leon Lu thanks this worked great. Here is my method `public async void DeleteAttendanceRecord(int studentID, DateTime dt)
        { await db.QueryAsync<Attendance>("DELETE FROM Attendance WHERE AttendanceDate =? AND StudentID =?", dt.Date, studentID); }` I'm able to use this without restructuring my table